# Ambiguous symbol

Tags: mosfet, rf, integrated-circuit, receiver, nmos

Does anybody know what this symbol presents?
[image]

Comment: Bilateral switch , aka 1 of Quad Transmission Gate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

*Figure 1. Tri-state buffers with opposite control logic. 
[Image source](http://www.deinfo.uepg.br/~ljsenger/tutoriais/tri-state-buffer.pdf).*

It's a combination or overlay of the two symbols in Figure 1.
Rotate the symbol on the right by 180° and overlay on the symbol on the left.

[image]

*Figure 2. Borrowing the symbol from KingDuken's answer but changing the infill to show the two buffers.*

If the control signal is high the gate transmits from left to right. If the control signal is low the gate transmits from right to left.

Comment: That's a really neat visual representation :) I like how you did that on Figure 2.

Comment: Workflow: [Greenshot](http://greenshot.org) screen grabber | [XNView](https://www.xnview.com/en/) image manipulation, using the *Levels* tool to remove the JPEG artifacts | paste into Windows Paint and use the good ol' paint can to fill. You can see that Paint hasn't covered the dithered pixels.

Answer (score 6):

As the others have said, it is a transmission gate. To further explain, these transmission gates are driven by CMOS-based switches and they behave similarly to a relay.

[image: Figure 1]

*Figure 1: Circuit equivalence and its symbol. Picture from [Electronic-Tutorials](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/combination/transmission-gate.html).*

It behaves very much so of a tristate buffer. Below is a truth table for such a device.

[image]

*Table 1: Truth Table for Transmission Gate. Table is on the same page as the previous link.*

Answer (score 3):

It's just a transmission gate. It will selectively block or pass a signal level from the input to the output.

Try a web search if you don't know how they work.

Comment: Web search if we know to search for transmission gate :)