# What name have this strange logic gate?

Tags: logic-gates, datasheet, atmel

Today I have looked over the port diagram presented in the datasheet for the Atmel 7810 controller (Chapter 13.2), in the logic diagram of the I/O ports, I noticed a strange logic gate, which I have not encountered until now and I have not found any information regarding this one.

***Logic gate picture:***
[image: Unknown gate]

What kind of logic gate is this? Is it a composite of two logic gates like "inverted buffered gates in mirror"?

I have no explanation in this regard.

Comment: Duplicate of [Ambiguous symbol](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/391657/ambiguous-symbol) which is itself a duplicate.

Comment: That isn't actually a logic gate per se, it is the logic symbol for a [transmission gate](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/combination/transmission-gate.html), one of the most basic building blocks of CMOS circuits.

Comment: @Transistor These questions only add to the Ambiguity

Comment: @Transiator , Caleb Reister , Thanks for clarify my concern. Voltage Spike I think the gates design in some datasheet are designed ambigous, because I lost almost 1 hour to figure out what that was. Symbols should be self-explanatory when a block is presented.

Comment: Hey I remember answering this question before with that duplicate question provided. Curses @Transistor for getting the accepted answer and not me haha :)

Comment: @King, I stood on your shoulders and nicked your illustration (with attribution, of course)!

Comment: @Transistor Not only that, you tagged this one a duplicate before KingDukem could get an answer in and have it be selected.

Comment: @Transistor Haha it's fine :) I'm just teasing around.