# what's that symbol in the attiny13a I/O schematic?

Tags: microcontroller, schematics, attiny, symbol, io

I was reading the ATtiny13A datasheet and I can't figure out what's that symbol in the general digital I/O schematic. I've circled it the figure below.
[image]

Comment: That's a MOS pass gate, I believe.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ambiguous symbol](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/391657/ambiguous-symbol) ... it's a transmission gate but I'm still flagging this as a duplicate question because the answer is the same.

Comment: a pass gate is a pmos and nmos with their drains and sources connected (s-s, d-d) and with their gates connected together through an inverter.  Effectively forming a 3-terminal (shared source,  shared drain, inverter input) device that acts like a digitally controlled bi-directional SPST switch. Pass gate logic is a whole thing you can read about.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the answer!